# Specifying a filter condition on a Text Search with MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to add a filter condition to a text search command against a MongoDB collection. I can successfully run the command in MongoLab, but I'm having trouble getting the correct syntax to execute the command via MongoDB C# driver.

The following returns all records matching the search condition but ignores the filter condition:

```
var textSearchCommand = new CommandDocument
{
    {"text", "Post"},
    {"search", "motorcycle"},
    {"filter", @"{""Type"":1}"}
};

var commandResult = this.Collection.Database.RunCommand(textSearchCommand);
```

Anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct syntax:

```
var filter = Query.EQ("Type", 1);
var textSearchCommand = new CommandDocument
{
    {"text", this.Collection.Name},
    {"search", searchString},
    {"filter", BsonValue.Create(filter)}
};

var commandResult = this.Collection.Database.RunCommand(textSearchCommand);
```